# asp mvc "A potentially dangerous Request.Form..."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm sending post with html to controller, and get exception in Chrome:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

.net 4.0, webserver is webdev at vs2010 my config:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
<assemblies>
<add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<pages validateRequest="false">
<namespaces>
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
<add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
</namespaces>
</pages>
```

...

what am i missing?

Comment: A little more detail, please.

Comment: Basically everything that would make this a coherent question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to set `[ValidateInput(false)]` on the Controller Action that you want to allow HTML for. (Or on the entire controller, but that's bad practice.

The other important thing is one that you got already, `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` in the web.config.

Setting RequestValidate in the .aspx files or web.config does not work in MVC as it's the controller, not the View that does request validation.

**Edit:** In the meantime, MVC 3 was released. This allows you to decorate individual properties of your model with [[AllowHtml]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=VS.98%29.aspx) to make them safe without completely disabling Request Validation.

Comment: @eba Be careful using this. Playing back these values to the user could cause XSS attacks. Html encoding is not enough to stop it.

Comment: Very good section in Professional ASP.NET MVC 4 (Galloway etc) about XSS and Html encoding - would highly recommend a read, but a strong recommend from them is to use AntiXSS as the default encoder on 4 (Nuget or http://wpl.codeplex.com/ ). 

....."AntiXSS uses a whitelist of allowed characters, whereas ASP.NET's default implementation uses a limited blacklist of disallowed characters. By allowing only known safe input, AntiXSS is more secure than a filter that tries to block potentially harmful input."....

Again, it's not THE solution, but it's stronger than allowing it all in...

Comment: -1 Incorrect. In .net 4.0, requestValidationModel applies to all requests, even mvc requests. See: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147

Answer (score 5):

If you are using MVC 3 RC then can use  new Attribute for your property as [AllowHtml]

*instead of setting [ValidateInput(false)] on the Controller Action.- this will not help you to prevent XSS attacks*

> *ASP.NET MVC includes built-in support to protect against HTML and Cross-Site
>   Script Injection Attacks, and will
>   throw an error by default if someone
>   tries to post HTML content as input. 
>   Developers need to explicitly indicate
>   that this is allowed (and that they’ve
>   hopefully built their app to securely
>   support it) in order to enable it.
>   With ASP.NET MVC 3, we are also now
>   supporting a new attribute that you
>   can apply to properties of
>   models/viewmodels to indicate that
>   HTML input is enabled, which enables
>   much more granular protection in a DRY
>   way.  In last month’s RC release this
>   attribute was named
>   [SkipRequestValidation].  With RC2 we
>   renamed it to [AllowHtml] to make it
>   more intuitive: Setting the above
>   [AllowHtml] attribute on a
>   model/viewmodel will cause ASP.NET MVC
>   3 to turn off HTML injection
>   protection when model binding just
>   that property.*